# Converting .tsv file to .txt creates unintended characters, possible fix?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Need to process a `.tsv` file that has 1 million lines and then save the file as a `.txt` file . I successfully am able to perform that this way:

```
import csv

with open("data.tsv") as fd, open('pre_processed_data.txt', 'wb') as csvout:
  rd = csv.reader(fd, delimiter="\t", quotechar='"')
  csvout = csv.writer(csvout,delimiter='\t')
  for row in rd:
      csvout.writerow([row[1],row[2],row[3]])
```

However, beyond a certain point , along with tabs certain special characters unintended crawls in. ie this way:

[image]

As you can see the first column expects only numeric values between 0 and 1. However special characters are seen in between.

What is possibly causing this and how to effectively resolve this?

Comment: How was the tsv generated?  Do you know its encoding?

Comment: @snakecharmerb This was a given dataset, no mention of the encoding is provided as such, is it an encoding issue, would opening the file as utf-8 encoded and saving it as utf-8 encoded txt fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

These extra characters exist in the input file.  As you have no cntrol over the file, the easiest thing to to do is to remove them as you process the data.  The re module's [sub](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) function can do this:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '1@'
>>> re.sub(r'\D+', '', s)
'1'
```

The `r'\D+'` pattern will match any non-numeric character for removal from the provided string.